# Combobox not updating bindtable fields in VB

Tags: vb.net, combobox, dropdownbox, databound

I have a combobox that is of type dropdown, i.e. allows user to either select something from the list or to type in a new value. Based on this combo value, other values are selected in the form automatically as they are databound.

Customer_ID is the field that needs to be picked or typed in, and based on it Customer first name and second name are updated in the form automatically. This works fine if I pick some value from dropdown, lets say Customer Id = 1111.

Now in place of picking, if i type in this value and press tab, no udpate happens on the Name fields. Please suggest what am I missing here.

Comment: What is the datasource for the combobox? If it is some type of observable collection you can use events on the data instead of the combobox.

Comment: Didn't understand your comment @Crowcoder ... what do you mean by observable collection?
I am basing my combobox on access database that will be just used to read data, no update of table happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you are going to do with the standard ComboBox is to handle the Leave event, or possibly the TextChanged event. I did some experimenting and typing in a value does not add to the list, it just changes the Text property. It doesn't even change the value of the item you typed over. And, it doesn't fire SelectedItem or IndexChanged events.
So if you handle the Leave event, you have a place to do your lookup when someone tabs off the ComboBox. But the item won't get added to the list.
If you need functionality not provided in the default control, you could redesign your UI with perhaps a TextBox and Button that add an item. Or, you could look for third party implementations of ComboBox controls that would have more functionality.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
        Dim theCB As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
        DoLookup(theCB.Text)
    End Sub
```